# panelgroup is updated after ajax render but the table inside it is not updated

Tags: ajax, jsf, xhtml

I have a table wrapped inside a panelgroup with a form, and I have a button which call a function in bean, and render all the panelgroup, but after button is clicked the panelgroup is refreshed but the table keep the previous values.

Here is my table

```
<table id="tableau" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead style=" background-color: #3f5367; color:white;">
   <tr>
     <th>Profil</th>
     <th>Agence</th>
     <th>Directeur de projet</th>
     <th>Date Entrée</th>
     <th>Date Départ</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <ui:repeat value="#{ressourceMB.travailles}" var="travaille" varStatus="status">
    <tr class="grade">
     <td class="center">#{travaille.profil.code_Profil}</td>
     <td class="center">#{travaille.agence.nom_Agence}</td>
     <td class="center">#{travaille.superieur.nom_Ressource} #{travaille.superieur.prenom_Ressource}</td>
     <td class="center"><h:outputText value ="#{travaille.date_Entree_Ressource}"><f:convertDateTime pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="CET"></f:convertDateTime></h:outputText></td>
     <td class="center"><h:outputText value ="#{travaille.date_Depart_Ressource}"><f:convertDateTime pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="CET"></f:convertDateTime></h:outputText></td>
    </tr>
   </ui:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my commandbutton

```
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 12px" value="Ajouter">
  <f:ajax listener="#{travailleMB.ajouterTravaille}" render="panelcode"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Actually after clicking on this button I add to the table "travailles" a new line and clear a form values.
The form values are cleared but the table keep same values.

This is the code of the whole panelgroup

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelcode">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <h:panelGroup id="panelcode2">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Profil *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;" >
                          <h:selectOneMenu value="#{travailleMB.selectedProfil}" title="Selectionner un profil" style="width:316px;height:34px; color:#555">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--- Choisir un Profil ---" />
                            <f:ajax listener="#{travailleMB.saveSelect}" process="@this"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ressourceMB.profils}" var="profil" itemLabel="#{profil.nom_Profil}" itemValue="#{profil.nom_Profil}"/> 
                          </h:selectOneMenu>
                          <br/>
                          <h:outputText value="#{travailleMB.requiredmsg}" style="color:red"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Agence *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 5px;" >
                          <h:selectOneMenu value="#{travailleMB.selectedAgence}" title="Selectionner une Agence" style="width:316px;height:34px; color:#555">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--- Choisir une Agence ---" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{ressourceMB.agences}" var="agence" itemLabel="#{agence.nom_Agence}" itemValue="#{agence.nom_Agence}"/>
                            <f:ajax render = "dps" listener="#{travailleMB.onAgenceSelect}" process="@this"/>
                          </h:selectOneMenu>
                          <br/>
                          <h:outputText value="#{travailleMB.requiredmsg2}" style="color:red"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Directeur de Projet 
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                          <h:selectOneMenu id="dps" value="#{travailleMB.selectedDp}" title="Selectionner un Directeur de projets" style="width:316px;height:34px; color:#555">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--- Choisir un Directeur de projet ---" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{travailleMB.ressourcesDp}" var="ressource" itemLabel="#{ressource.nom_Ressource} #{ressource.prenom_Ressource}" itemValue="#{ressource.id_Ressource}"/>                             
                             <f:ajax listener="#{travailleMB.saveSelect}" process="@this"/>
                          </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date-entree">Date Entrée <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="row calendar-exibit col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <fieldset style="margin-bottom: -10px">
                          <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                              <div class="col-md-11 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback" style="width: 85.667%; padding-left: 0px; border-radius: 3px;">
                                <p:calendar class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" locale="fr" id="dentree" value="#{travailleMB.dateentree}" placeholder="--- Date Entrée ---" style="border-radius: 3px; font-size: 12px; padding-right: 9px; padding-top: 3px;"/>
                                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{travailleMB.saveSelect}" process="@this"/>
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{travailleMB.requiredmsg1}" style="color:red; font-size:12px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.471; margin-left: 6%"></p:outputLabel>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date-depart">Date Départ 
                        </label>
                        <div class="row calendar-exibit col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <fieldset style="margin-bottom: -10px">
                          <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                              <div class="col-md-11 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback" style="width: 85.667%; padding-left: 0px; border-radius: 3px;">
                                <p:calendar class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" locale="fr" id="ddepart" value="#{travailleMB.datedepart}" placeholder="--- Date Depart ---" style="border-radius: 3px; font-size: 12px; padding-right: 9px; padding-top: 3px;" />
                                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{travailleMB.saveSelect}" process="@this"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </h:panelGroup>
                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                           
                          <h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" id="reset1" style="font-size: 12px" value="Reinitialiser">
                            <f:ajax render="panelcode2" listener="#{travailleMB.clear}"></f:ajax>
                          </h:commandButton>
                           
                          <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 12px" value="Ajouter">
                             <f:ajax listener="#{travailleMB.ajouterTravaille}" render="panelcode"/>
                          </h:commandButton>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="font-size: 11.19px">
                    <table id="tableau" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead style=" background-color: #3f5367; color:white;">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Profil</th>
                          <th>Agence</th>
                          <th>Directeur de projet</th>
                          <th>Date Entrée</th>
                          <th>Date Départ</th>
                          <th style="color: #3f5367"><div style="color: white;padding-bottom:0px;text-align:center;">Modifier</div></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{ressourceMB.travailles}" var="travaille" varStatus="status">
                        <tr class="grade">
                            <td class="center">#{travaille.profil.code_Profil}</td>
                            <td class="center">#{travaille.agence.nom_Agence}</td>
                            <td class="center">#{travaille.superieur.nom_Ressource} #{travaille.superieur.prenom_Ressource}</td>
                            <td class="center"><h:outputText value ="#{travaille.date_Entree_Ressource}"><f:convertDateTime pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="CET"></f:convertDateTime></h:outputText></td>
                            <td class="center"><h:outputText value ="#{travaille.date_Depart_Ressource}"><f:convertDateTime pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="CET"></f:convertDateTime></h:outputText></td>
                            <td><h:form>
                            <h:commandLink
                              action="#" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-left: 21%; padding:0px 0px ; background-color: #5bc0de; border-color: #46b8da">
                              <span><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: white; padding: 1px 6px"></i></span>
                            </h:commandLink>
                            </h:form></td>
                        </tr>
                        </ui:repeat>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
              </h:panelGroup>
```

and this is the method that add the line to table "travaille" in database and also the list "travailles" that populate the table in my xhtml page.

```
//TODO Methode Ajouter Travaille
    public void ajouterTravaille() throws ParseException{
        System.out.println("Accès a la methode d'ajout Travaille");
        requiredmsg = "";
        requiredmsg1 = null;
        requiredmsg2 = null;
        
        System.out.println("le selected profil est : "+selectedProfil);
        System.out.println("la selected agence est : "+selectedAgence);
        if(selectedDp!= null){
            System.out.println("le directeur de projets est : "+ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(selectedDp).getNom_Ressource());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("le directeur de projets est : "+selectedDp);
        }
        System.out.println("la date entrée est : "+dateentree);
        System.out.println("la date départ est : "+datedepart);
        
        
        if(selectedProfil == null){
            requiredmsg="Veuillez renseigner ce champ";
            selectedProfil=null;
        }
        if(dateentree == null){
            requiredmsg1="Veuillez renseigner ce champ";
            dateentree = null;
        }
        if(selectedAgence == null){
            requiredmsg2="Veuillez renseigner ce champ";
            selectedAgence=null;
        }
        if(selectedProfil == null || dateentree == null || selectedAgence == null){
            // SI un seul champ requis est vide
            System.out.println("Champs requis est vide travaille");
        }
        else{// SI aucun champs requis n'est vide il faut verfier les conditions de dates
            
            // charger les travailles de la ressource dans une liste
            List<Travaille> trvs=travailleRepository.Chercherparressource(ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(RessourceMB.id));
            // enregistrer le dernier enregistrement de la liste
            Travaille trv = trvs.get(trvs.size()-1);
            
            // verifier si la ressource a une date de depart
            if(trv.getDate_Depart_Ressource()==null){
                System.out.println("Pas de date depart pour la ressource travaille");
            }
            else if(trv.getDate_Depart_Ressource().compareTo(dateentree)==0 || trv.getDate_Depart_Ressource().compareTo(dateentree)<0){
                // l'ajout il faut mettre à jour les données de l'enregistrement de la ressource
                ProfilRessource pr = profilRessourceRepository.Chercherparnom(selectedProfil);
                Agence ag = agenceRepository.Chercherparnom(selectedAgence);
                Ressource dp = ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(selectedDp);
                
                Ressource rc=ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(RessourceMB.id);
                
                travailleRepository.save(new Travaille(ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(RessourceMB.id), dp, pr, ag, dateentree, datedepart));
                
                System.out.println("id ressource a modifier est : " +rc.getNom_Ressource());
                
                ressourceRepository.Updateprofilressource(pr, rc.getId_Ressource());
                ressourceRepository.Updateentreeressource(dateentree, rc.getId_Ressource());
                ressourceRepository.Updatedepartressource(datedepart, rc.getId_Ressource());
                ressourceRepository.Updateagenceressource(ag, rc.getId_Ressource());
                ressourceRepository.Updatedpressource(dp, rc.getId_Ressource());    
                
                travailles=travailleRepository.Chercherparressource(ressourceRepository.Chercherparid(RessourceMB.id));
                System.out.println("table travailles populated");
                
                selectedProfil=null; selectedAgence=null; selectedDp=null; dateentree=null; datedepart=null; 
                
            }

        }
        System.out.println("date entrée avant la date de depart");
        }
```

this picture can show what happened when I click the button [AJOUTER] and as you can see the form is cleared but no changes on the table.
[image of the page on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hATRT.png)

Comment: Hi @AyoubM, welcome to SO! It would help to answer your question if you append the whole panelGroup code, and also the method to add a new line.

Comment: HI @Bonifacio , i updated my question, add the whole panelgroup code and the method that add the line to the list, hope this help you to find an answer to my issue.

Comment: Seems like your panelGroup is not rendering with id="panelcode"  when rendered on browser. As a test, please change the render="panelcode" to render="@form".

Comment: i tried with @form and nothing changed.

Comment: I edited my question again, and added a picture of the page on browser to show you what it's like, and you can see the parts page part updated when i click on the commandbutton. thanks @Bonifacio

Comment: Well in this case JSF seems to be doing it's job correctly. Maybe your problem is in the database persist? Also, instead of saving it in the database, try to first add the object to your list. In this case even if your database throws an error, you will be able to see if the list is changed or not.

Comment: i'm now adding the object to the list before saving it into the database, and display the list on the console, so i'm sure that the object is correctly added, i check after that the table on database and the line is correctly added , but the table on my page is still the same. To display the updated values i have to go to another page and get back to this one.